# Multisite Drupal 7 sharing same code base

Tags: subsites

I have existing Drupal 7 site and I want to create a sub-domain using the multisite feature of drupal.

I followed all the steps required for drupal multisite as below.

Suppose my existing site url is www.abc.com and I want to make a sub-domain as www.jobs.abc.com

Steps I followed.

1. Under sites folder I created a new folder jobs.abc.com and copied the default.settings.php file renamed it as settings.php

   sites/jobs.abc.com/settings.php

2.My existing domain settings.php file is under default folder sites/default/settings.php

3.I Renamed the example.sites.php to sites.php and added the following two lines.

$sites['www.abc.com'] = 'default';
$sites['www.jobs.abc.com'] = 'jobs.abc.com';

Finally I installed the Multisite wizard module http://ftp.drupal.org/files/projects/multisite_wizard-7.x-1.3.tar.gz

I configured the module it is showing me the message

"Hint: the folders names should be the same as values of domain-folder array in the site.php file
Folders to be created: default,job.abc.com" please find the screenshot.

[image]

I have already created these folders there. I am not sure why its showing this message again.

Comment: Are you sure that you have created the folders in the proper directory and that they are browsable by the server? Supposing that you have your drupal installed in /var/www/mydrupal, the following folders should exist: /var/www/mydrupal/sites/default and /var/www/mydrupal/sites/jobs.abc.com and the server (usually Apache) should be the owner of the directories (usually www-data user). If it's not try to change the ownership (in Linux the command looks like: chown -R www-data:www-data /var/www/mydrupal/sites/jobs.abc.com )

Comment: I have created the same folders, even both the folders contains the settings.php files, do not understand why the folders are not detected. Regarding the ownership I will check with this.

Comment: I have condensed my comment in an answer for posterity reasons.

Answer (score 1):

Having the folders that the message states in your sites/ directory involves two basic steps:

1. Creating the directories
2. Making the directories visible to the web server

In a typical Ubuntu installation with Apache as your server the first step is accomplished by executing the `mkdir` command in your sites directory:

Example

```
cd /var/www/my_drupal_site/sites
mkdir jobs.abc.com
```

and for the second step using the `chown` command.

```
chown -R www-data:www-data default
chown -R www-data:www-data jobs.abc.com
```

The chown command changes the ownership of the directory and with the -R flag it does the same thing recursively for every contained subdirectory and file. The www-data is the default user and group that Apache runs as (so if you have an nginx setup, you will probably have to change this).